# Error occurs when creating Xtext project in Eclipse, using Gradle and Buildship

Tags: eclipse, gradle, xtext, buildship

I am learning about Xtext, and am following the 5 Minutes Tutorial found here:

https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/101_five_minutes.html

I started by downloading and installing the Eclipse Mars package called "Eclipse IDE for Java and DSL Developers" (eclipse-dsl-mars-2-win32-x86_64.zip). This package includes Xtext and Xtend.

I then installed Buildship via the Eclipse Marketplace.

Continuing with the tutorial, I followed these steps:

- Create a new Xtext project by choosing File → New → Project… from the main menu. Select New Xtext Project from the category Xtext.
- Keep the project and language names as proposed and continue via Next.
- Select all of the offered Facets, choose the Gradle build system, and finish the wizard.

The first time I tried these steps, everything worked fine. Gradle built nine projects for me, as expected. I continued with the tutorial and was able to create a simple DSL called "MyDsl".

Now I want to create my own DSL, but the process above no longer works. When I try to create a new Xtext project in Eclipse, I get an error message like this:

[image: Eclipse error message]

The Problems view in Eclipse looks like this:

[image: Eclipse Problems view]

Looking at the file system, I can confirm that the "prefs" files listed in the Problems view are present in the first Xtext project I created (the one that worked), but are missing in all the subsequent projects I have tried to create.

So it appears that one part of the build is supposed to create those files, but is failing to do so, and a subsequent part of the build is throwing the error because the files are not present.

I have had no luck finding any information about this problem on the web.

I am working on a Windows system, and have configured Eclipse to use JDK 1.8.0_45.

So far I have tried the following to resolve the problem:

- I created a brand new workspace in Eclipse, and tried the tutorial again, exactly as before.
- I uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled it, then reinstalled Buildship from Eclipse marketplace, then tried the tutorial again.

No luck.

Does anyone have any thoughts about what might be going on here? Or how I can troubleshoot the problem?

**Update:** The link from Christian Dietrich helped me find a workaround for this problem. The error occurs only when Buildship is installed, so to create a new Xtext project, you can uninstall Buildship, create the project, then reinstall Buildship. Takes a little more time, but it works.

Comment: this is a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492728

Comment: Thanks for the link!